# <asp:GridView> width, <div> width

Tags: asp.net, html, css, firefox

i have the following markup code:

```
<div style="width: 72%; margin: 15px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <center>
        <div style="border-top: Solid 1px Black; border-left: Solid 1px Black; border-right: Solid 1px Black;
        padding: 5px; background-color: #EEEEEE;">
        </div>
        <asp:GridView Style="width: 100%;" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Black">
        </asp:GridView>
    </center>
</div>
```

the result is this :

[image]

what might be the cause of that alignment discrepancy at the top left?

EDIT: this only happens in firefox. i wonder how i should approach the problem. trivial i know but hey.

Comment: It happens only in firefox. It works well at IE.

Comment: what does the generated html for the GridView look like?

Comment: The discrepancy also shows in Chrome, fwiw!

Comment: @jester, thanks for taking the time to test it, but i found it to work fine in chrome!

Comment: I ridiculously thought the image in your question was rendering the html in question. D'oh! If you prefer, go ahead and delete your reply and I'll delete my comment above ("The discrepancy also shows in Chrome, fwiw!") so we can unclutter these comments, if you like.

Comment: haha. nah, leave it, maybe someone will read it and smile.

Answer (score 1):

The border of the grid (which is a table) is outside the 100% width (this is the way standards mode CSS works). Also the center tag is depreciated in standards mode.

A trick you could use to fix this problem is to rewrite the inner div tag to be a table like the grid:

```
<table style="border-top: Solid 1px Black; border-left: Solid 1px Black; 
  border-right: Solid 1px Black; border-collapse:collapse; 
  background-color: #EEEEEE; width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style='padding: 5px'>(inner stuff)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That way it will have the same identical border outside the  table.